# Dealing with RollbackException in Java

Tags: java, transactions, rollback

Is there any way to "replay" transaction? 
I mean, sometimes I get RollbackException and rollback the transaction. Can I then "clone" the transaction and try again, or once rollback is called, transaction is lost? 
I really need the changes, and really don't want to trace every change for rerunning later...

thanks, 
udi

Answer (score 0):

Why do you get the exception in the first place ? This seems to me to be the crux of the matter.

Are you relying on optimistic writing ? If so, then you'll have to wrap your database writes in some form of loop, incorporating (perhaps) a backoff and a number of retries. You can't do this automatically, unfortunately (unless you investigate some form of [AOP](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) solution wrapping your database writes with a retry strategy ?)

Answer (score 0):

That depends where that transaction comes from. In Java/JDBC, a transaction is tied to a connection. You start one by setting `setAutoCommit()` to false (otherwise, every statement becomes its own little transaction).

There is nothing preventing you from reusing the connection after a transaction failed (i.e. you called rollback).

Things get more tricky when you use Spring. Spring wraps your methods in a transaction handler and this handler tries to guess what it should do with the current transaction from the exceptions that get thrown in the method. The next question is: Which wrapper created the current transaction? I just had a case where I would call a method `foo()` which would in turn call `bar()`, both `@Transactional`.

I wanted to catch errors from `bar()` in `foo()` and save them into the DB. That didn't work because the transaction was created for `foo()` (so I was still in a transaction which Spring thought broken by the exception in `bar()`) and it wouldn't let me save the error.

The solution was to create `baz()`, make it `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` and call it from `foo()`. `baz()` would get a new, fresh transaction and would be able to write to the DB even though it was called from `foo()` which already had a (broken) transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use [JDBC savepoints](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) to partly roll back.

Comment: As far as I understand, the savepoing doesn't help in this specific case, cause rolling back to the last savepoint does not preserve the data updated later..